# Is this enough to disprove this statement?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, vectors, vector-analysis, plane-geometry

I'm trying to disprove the following:

[image]

I've done this by considering the second equation with the values listed below:

$$A = -a$$
$$B = -b$$
$$C = -c $$
$$D = -d $$

This should still be parallel to the first plane right? Negative all the coefficients only flips the side of it. From this, consider any point with any values for $a,b,c,d$ and find that the planes are still parallel but the coefficients are not equivalent.

Does this hold up?

Comment: Yes if you take the negative of each constant, then you will get the same equation if you rearrange the terms. So what you said is correct.

Comment: This certainly works. Of course, if $a = A$, etc. then the two planes actually coincide, so the assertion would imply that there are no two distinct planes which are parallel, which is certainly false.

Comment: @Travis : Yes, I didn't read carefully. I've already deleted my comment, sorry.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate the help!

Comment: This is correct. An even clearer counterexample could use numbers. Set $a=b=c=A=B=C=d=1$ and $D=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can use that $$\vec{n_1}=(a;b;c)$$ and $$\vec{n_2}=(A;B;C)$$ are linear dependend